# I want to check whether first and last letters of the words are same to return True else false. But it returns true every time

Tags: python-3.x, loops

```
def first_last(message):
    for char in message:
        if char[0] == char[-1]:
            return True
        elif message == "":
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I'm using it like this:

```
print(first_last("night")) # should return False
print(first_last("nun")) # should return True
print(first_last(""))   # should return true
```

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Comment: If you want to check the first and the last character only, why do you loop over all the characters?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `for loop` you get a single character from `message`, then your comparison is meaningless.

You can try this:

```py
def start_and_end_are_same(message):
    if message[:1] == message[-1:]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(start_and_end_are_same('night'))
print(start_and_end_are_same('nun'))
print(start_and_end_are_same(''))
```

Comment: Would simply `return message[:1] == message[-1:]` be considered un-pythonic? Because to me it's much simpler and equally readable.

Comment: I don't know, but i think `return message[:1] == message[-1:]` may be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to loop through all characters.

```
def first_last(message): 
    if message == "": 
        return True 
    elif message[0] == message[-1]: 
        return True 
    else: return False
```

Comment: This will fail on the empty string

Comment: just swap first and second check. use your imagination.